# Building Qt Application using OpenSSL and CMake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, openssl

I want to build my Qt application using QNetworkAuth which needs OpenSSL.
Now, I do have qt 5.9, openssl 1.1.0 and 1.0.2 in my system, im trying to force cmake to link against the version 1.0.2.

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}Client /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 Qt5::Gui Qt5::Qml Qt5::NetworkAuth)
```

my problem is that when I try to run my app I am still getting errors like:

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_num_locks
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_id_callback
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
```

What do I need to do to fix it?
Thank you very much.

Comment: If you're trying to link against version 1.0.2, should you be referencing version `1.0.2` of the libraries rather than `1.0.0` like you have specified in your `target_link_libraries`?

Comment: LD is a single pass linker. Order matters, and the library that "depends on X" should be listed before "X". Use`Qt5::Gui Qt5::Qml Qt5::NetworkAuth /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0` instead.